# pgfplots, axis limits and axis equal

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to apply the `axis equal` option and scale the y-axis from 0 to pi. Unfortunately both is not working with the minimal example provided below. The output still contains white filled space in the plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        shader=interp,
        axis equal,
        view={0}{90},
%       ymin=0,
%       ymax=pi,
        xlabel={$\varphi$},
        ylabel={$\theta$},
        ylabel style={rotate=90},
        y dir=reverse,
        colorbar horizontal]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=20,
            domain=0:2*pi,
            y domain=0:pi] {cos(deg(2*x))*sin(deg(2*y))}; 
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `axis equal image`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what `axis equal image` is for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        shader=interp,
        axis equal image,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel={$\varphi$},
        ylabel={$\theta$},
        ylabel style={rotate=90},
        y dir=reverse,
        colorbar horizontal]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=20,
            domain=0:2*pi,
            y domain=0:pi] {cos(deg(2*x))*sin(deg(2*y))}; 
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```