how can draw conical helix with latex tikz picture?
I am not much better at mathematics equations, but I need to draw some graphs in latex. I tried this one but it's not look exactly the same as shown in the image. Please I will be very grateful if anyone can help regarding this.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.topaths.arcthrough, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        hide axis, % Hide the axis lines, labels, and ticks
        view={45}{45},
        axis equal,
        grid=none,
        samples=50,
        domain=0:7*pi,
    ]
    % First helix shifted upwards
    \addplot3[black, smooth] 
    ({x*cos(deg(x))}, {x*sin(deg(x))}, {x + 1});
    
    % Second helix shifted downwards
    \addplot3[black, smooth] 
    ({-x*cos(deg(x))}, {-x*sin(deg(x))}, {-x - 1});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Are the two not  supposed to join at x-0?   OTOH, the image looks like the two are rotated 90^\circ relative to each other.

Yes the origin of both is common.

Note: This is the second update of this answer. The first one added the \addplot3[] ({},{},{}); syntax, and this update adds `samplesy=<>

This is a solution using the \draw[variable=\t] plot ({},{},{});, and \addplot3[] ({},{},{}); syntaxes:
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%% START
ymin=-5,ymax=5,
xmin=-5,xmax=5,
zmin=-5,zmax=5,
view={60}{30},
samples y=1, % See comments section
axis equal,
]%%% END
\draw[blue,variable=\Vt,smooth,domain=-360:360,samples=500] plot ({(5*\Vt/360)*cos(10*\Vt)},{(5*\Vt/360)*sin(10*\Vt)},{5*\Vt/360});
\addplot3[red,domain=-360:360,samples=50] ({5*x/360*cos(10*x)},{5*x/360*sin(10*x)},{5*x/360});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Please can you explain why the axis points are not equal?

@SamiaRani Try using axis equal image instead of axis equal Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227761/319072

It worked for me. Thank you so much

You need samples y=1 for a line plot in 3D in PGFPlots

It compiled a lot faster when I did that. Thanks for the input
